# Forbid access to a file by url but allow through browser

Tags: magento2, htaccess, file-permissions

how can I prevent the user to access my **/v** folder in my website where I have some video, but allow them to be display on frontend thanks to  the <\video> tag from HTML 5 ?

I tried this and other stuff in my /v folder :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://sub.domain.com [NC]  
RewriteRule \.(mp4)$ - [F]
```

but the fill is not forbidden (cache already cleared)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your Apache version and env configuration:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!sub.domain.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.mp4$"    "-"   [F,NC]
```

but correct way also to load your files from within application itself, add random hashed request in php to load / get files. and hide location **/v**.

so request is not: `/path/to/v/video.mp4`

but will be hashed request: `/path/to/hash_8475nd784tn84gndofjewbc83/video.mp4`